# How to efficiently check the time to fire an event?

Tags: events, unity-game-engine

This is a larger question about how computers are able to fire tasks based off a time trigger.

I'm building a game in Unity with a GameManager singleton Instance that runs a game clock. I want events to happen periodically throughout the game, but it seems inefficient and counter-intuitive to run a time variable through a series of if-statements to know when an event should happen.

I've also been developing mobile apps, and I've always wondered how an alarm works (is this similar to the above context?). Does the device/underlying tasks run 24hours of the day and wait by checking the equivalent of an if-statement to know when to alert the alarm event?

Comment: Unity's `MonoBehaviour` provides the `Invoke`, `InvokeRepeating`, and `StartCoroutine` functions for this purpose. Refer to the manual for further information. If im not completely mistaken, there also are official tutorials provided for that (and if not, there are plenty on ytube).

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is basically how computers do events. most event-driven programs including the OS itself use what is called a pooling system where the system will go throw a large list of all existing events and check if their firing condition is met. This firing condition can be a time or other triggers such as input being received from a device like a keyboard or network card.

The Unity engine actually does this too. Behind the scenes, Unity will have a main process running constantly checking if the firing conditions for all the built-in monobehaviour methods have been met and then firing the methods if they have. For example, the FixedUpdate method is guaranteed to be called so many times per second, i believe its 30 times a second but i'm not sure off the top of my head. so the calling method for fixed update would simply be something like this.

```
timer += Time.deltaTime();
while(timer >= (1.0f/30.0f))
{
    FixedUpdate();
    timer -= (1.0f/30.0f);
}
```

This code would run as often as the processor would allow, constantly checking if enough time has passed to perform another call to FixedUpdate(), this code also performs backdating so if the processor become overloaded and this code doesn't get called for say 2 seconds then the next time it gets called it will perform enough calls for the 2 seconds that were missed.

Now for your unity application, if this is going to be small class say only around 10 time conditions then i would just use if statements as you suggest any more than that and i would start considering taking a more oop approach and have a abstract class with two methods

```
abstract class ConditionEvent{
    bool ConditionMet();
    void Process();
}
```

Then in your MonoBehavour call i would have a list of filled with these classes with a loop that calls the ConditionMet function. If the function returns true then call Process.